# Where did the "Search in Project" context menu item go in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

When you selected text in the code window and right-clicked on it, you would get a context menu with an option to "Search in Project" for the selected text. (Xcode 3.x)

Anyone knows how I can achieve the same in Xcode 4? Or a keyboard shortcut?

Now I select the text and wrestle my fingers in the following combination CMD-C, CMD-CTRL-F, CMD-V, RETURN. Feels a bit like playing the Playstation...

Cheers,
Niels R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a single keyboard shortcut, but one you might find useful is "Use Selection for Find" (Command+E). That is, you can select some text, and press Command+E, Command+Shift+F, Return.

Answer (score 3):

It's no longer in a menu option but is accessible by an icon.  Look directly beneath the "Schemes" at the sequence of 7 small icons.  The 3rd one over is a "search" icon.  Click that icon and type in your project search text and press return.

Comment: This sucks.  I much much much preferred a context menu, ... I'm having a difficult time adjusting to Xcode 4 for this exact reason.

Answer (score 3):

Just think it might be handy to see it at a glance:

[image: ScreenShot of XCode]