# searching a variable in whole project

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4

hii every one

in xcode 4 where is the option to search a variable in whole project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit->Find->Find in Workspace...

**Update:** As pointed out in a comment, **Find** is a top-level menu in recent versions of Xcode, so it's now: just Find->Find in Workspace...

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> and you can type the search text in dialog

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the variable
2. Right click
3. See the option 'Find in Project'
4. Then click 'As Text'.
5. Done. :)

Answer (score 1):

See this...

[Where did the "Search in Project" context menu item go in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323175/where-did-the-search-in-project-context-menu-item-go-in-xcode-4)